# Parse and compare XML tag text to get siblings

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am parsing NOAA XML that looks like so:

```
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
<layout-key>k-p12h-n14-1</layout-key>
<start-valid-time period-name="Tonight">2012-12-18T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Wednesday">2012-12-19T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Wednesday Night">2012-12-19T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Thursday">2012-12-20T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Thursday Night">2012-12-20T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Friday">2012-12-21T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Friday Night">2012-12-21T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Saturday">2012-12-22T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Saturday Night">2012-12-22T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday">2012-12-23T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday Night">2012-12-23T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Monday">2012-12-24T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Monday Night">2012-12-24T18:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Christmas Day">2012-12-25T06:00:00-08:00</start-valid-time>
</time-layout>
```

There are other  tags in the document, but I would like the **k-p12h-n14-1** tag.

How do I get the period-name="*" for just the period names that follow the k-p12h-n14-1?

Here is a [FULL XML FILE EXAMPLE](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.36354&lon=-118.39511010000001&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml)

I have tried to figure it out using:

```
List<XmlDom> wxday = xml.tags("time-layout","time-coordinate","summarization");
String wxd = wxday.child("layout-key");
String wxdd = wxday.equals("k-p12h-n14-1");
kind of lost....
```

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
    File fXmlFile = new File("MapClick.php.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodeList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("layout-key");
    int size = nodeList.getLength();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);

        if (currentNode.getTextContent().trim().equals("k-p12h-n14-1")) {
            while (currentNode.getNextSibling() != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getNextSibling();

                if (currentNode.getNodeName().equals("start-valid-time")) {
                    System.out.println(((Element)currentNode).getAttribute("period-name"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```